# SQL Server Change Tracking

Tags: sql-server

I work for a company of about 80 employees and they all seem to need access to our database on a regular basis. I don't have time to write applications to meet all of their needs so I'm just going to install SQL Server Management Studio on each employee's computer so they can help themselves to the data. Does anyone know if there's a way to write a wrapper for SQL Server that would save all database transactions to a text file so I can monitor what changes everyone is making?

Comment: This is a terrible idea for a lot of reasons.  "I don't have time" is not a great reason to give everyone the keys to the store.

Comment: You are in for a world of trouble giving everyone access to the data.  _Oops I truncated a table_

Comment: Most of the people I work with have college degrees so I can just teach them how to write SQL code. That should eliminate the risk of truncation issues.

Comment: @TropicThunder are you talking about read only access?

Comment: @Zane: No, full access. I need them to be able to insert, update, and delete.

Answer (score 11):

I may get dinged for this, I may not, but if you don't have time I've got a **fantastic** solution for you. Download Visual Studio LightSwith - you can build a database application in less than five minutes and have it deployed in less than ten - I've done it.

Make time, find the right tools, but ***do not give them the keys to the database.***

In fact, LightSwitch is so dead simple, you could teach some other folks there how to use it at some level.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't agree with your motives 'I don't have time'  I do understand the need.

Ensure you have appropriate security setup for that portion, and for your data changes you want to Checkout [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) if you are on SQL2008R2 which of course is available in 2012  as well, below that you will have to roll your own solution using triggers, but i doubt you'll have time for that.